# Question about error Info in xsl:try xsl:catch

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

The code is from:[try-catch-examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#try-catch-examples):

```
<xsl:result-document href="out.xml">
  <xsl:variable name="result">
      <xsl:call-template name="construct-output"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:try>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$result" validation="strict"/>
    <xsl:catch>
      <xsl:message>Warning: validation of result document failed:
          Error code: <xsl:value-of select="$err:code"/>
          Reason: <xsl:value-of select="$err:description"/>
      </xsl:message>
      <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:catch>
  </xsl:try>
</xsl:result-document>
```

what syntax is the `$err:code`, `$err:description`? The "`$err`" seems to be a variable, why it's followed by a colon? What type is it?  What type are `code`,`description`? a key string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what syntax is the $err:code, $err:description? The "$err" seems to be
>   a variable, why it's followed by a colon? What type is it? What type
>   are code,description? a key string?

**`$somePrefix:localName`** is a variable reference whose name belongs to a namespace and the prefix **`somePrefix`** is associated to that namespace.

In this particular case the `err` prefix is associated with **[the standard error namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#dt-standard-error-namespace)**: `http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors`

**The exact meaning is explained in the [XSLT 3.0 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#try-catch-examples)**:

"Within the select expression, or within the sequence constructor contained by the xsl:catch element, **a number of variables are implicitly declared**, giving information about the error that occurred. These are lexically scoped to the xsl:catch element. These variables are all in the standard error namespace, and they are initialized as described in the following table:"

[image]

The phrase: "*a number of variables are implicitly declared*" from the above quotation is key to understanding how an error is caught in the **[`xsl:catch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#element-catch)** element

It means that whenever an error is caught in `xsl:catch`, the XSLT processor itself creates these variables and they are provided to the programmer to use inside the scope of the `xsl:catch` element.

We can say that each of these variables is a "*future*" that may be created by the XSLT processor acting as a "*promise*" -- for the exact meaning see: 
["**Futures and promises**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)

Comment: Can the prefix of error be omitted when his namespace is declared in root tag?

Comment: No, typically there are many namespace declarations in scope and the prefix is what identifies the namespace -- unless this namespace is declared as the default namespace -- something that nobody normally does. As this is a complete answer to the question, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @cmf41013 You can use a different prefix ("err" is just a convention), but you must use a prefix because otherwise you would be referring to a no-namespace variable. If you're keen to avoid cluttering your code with namespace declarations, you can also refer to the `$err:code` variable as `$Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors}code`

Comment: Note also, re Dimitre's answer to your comment, an unprefixed variable name is always treated as being in no namespace; there is no way of setting a default namespace that applies to variable names (the same is true for template names, etc).

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks, why we can omit the xpath "fn" prefix,  when  we code in xslt , such as the `fn:position()` function.  But not allowing omit `err` prefix?

Comment: @cmf41013 In XSLT 1.0, only built-in functions were available, and they used unprefixed names. The idea of putting them in a namespace was invented when XQuery came along, but XSLT retained backwards compatibility by saying that although they were technically in a namespace, there was a default namespace for functions and unprefixed names were treated as being in that namespace.

Comment: Ok, I totally understand.